# how to search observation collection inside observation collection in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to xamarin.

I want to search the MallUnitNo in the below type of Observable Collection. But I did not get any idea.

I tried the code below. But it crash when search.

ViewModel Class:

```
    namespace xxx.Models
    {


        public class UtilityListModel : ObservableCollection<ShopDet>, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public string LeaseName { get; set; }
            public string LeaseDate { get; set; }
            public string LeaseNo { get; set; }
            private bool _expanded;

            public string TitleWithItemCount
            {
                get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", LeaseName, LeaseDate, LeaseNo); }
            }


            public bool Expanded
            {
                get { return _expanded; }
                set
                {
                    if (_expanded != value)
                    {
                        _expanded = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Expanded");
                        OnPropertyChanged("StateIcon");
                    }
                }
            }

            public string StateIcon
            {
                get { return Expanded ? "twoArrowup.png" : "twoArrowdown.png"; }
            }


            public UtilityListModel(string leasename, string leaseno, string leasedate, bool expanded = true)
            {
                LeaseName = leasename;
                LeaseNo = leaseno;
                LeaseDate = leasedate;
                Expanded = expanded;
            }




            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
            public class ShopDet
        {


            public string ShopName { get; set; }
            public string ShopDate { get; set; }

            public string MallName { get; set; }
            public string MallPlace { get; set; }
            public string MallProduct { get; set; }
            public string MallUnitNo { get; set; }
            public string TimePeriod { get; set; }


            public string UtilityType { get; set; }
            public string StartReading { get; set; }
            public string EndReading { get; set; }
            public string UnitConsumed { get; set; }
            public string UnitRate { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<ShopDet> MallDetails { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<ShopDet> MeterDetails { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<ShopDet> ShopDetails { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

This is how I search for the specific property:

```
private void SearchBar_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _expandedGroups = new ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            UpdateListContent();

        }

        else
        {
            foreach (UtilityListModel group in _allGroups)
            {
                var matches = new ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel>(group.Where(p => p.MallDetails.Contains((PEMS.Models.ShopDet)(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue))).ToList());




                if (matches.Any())
                {

                    _expandedGroups.Add(group);
                }

            }
            Utilitylistview.ItemsSource = _expandedGroups;

        }
    }
```

Below is a test data and hopefully will give you an idea of the UtilityListModel:

```
ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel> allGroups = new ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel> {
    new UtilityListModel ("Royal Golden Sky Company Limited", "JC-LA-201612-000190", "from 01/04/2017 to 31/03/2020", false) 
    {
        new ShopDet 
        {
            ShopDate = "from 01/04/2017 to 31/03/2020", ShopName = "COACH ( SJC001002-0003 )",
            MallDetails = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet> 
            {
                new ShopDet { MallName = "JUNCTION CITY", MallPlace = "Phase 1 → Level 1", MallUnitNo = "01-003", MallProduct = "Shoes & Bags", TimePeriod = "for period of 01/02/2020 to 29/02/2020" },
            }, 
            MeterDetails = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet> 
            {
                new ShopDet { UtilityType = "MEPE - Generator (34162530310)", StartReading = "0", EndReading = "Nil", UnitConsumed = "223.00", UnitRate = "Rate per unit: 200.00 up to 999999999 units" },
                new ShopDet { UtilityType = "MEPE - Sub Meter (34162530310)", StartReading = "0", EndReading = "Nil", UnitConsumed = "223.00", UnitRate = "Rate per unit: 200.00 up to 999999999 units" },
            }
        },
    },
    new UtilityListModel ("Myanmar Bakery Co. Ltd ","JC-LA-201612-000191","from  01/04/2017 to 31/03/2020", false)
    {
        new ShopDet 
        {
            ShopDate = "from 01/04/2017 to 31/03/2020", 
            ShopName = "BreadTalk(SJC001010-0011) ", 
            MallDetails = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet> 
            {
                new ShopDet { MallName = "JUNCTION CITY", MallPlace = "Phase 1 → Level 1", MallUnitNo = "01-011/012", MallProduct = "Food & Beverages", TimePeriod = "TimePeriod 01/02/2020 to 29/02/2020" },
            }, 
            MeterDetails = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet> 
            {
                new ShopDet { UtilityType = "Water Meter (16003372)", StartReading = "0", EndReading = "Nil", UnitConsumed = "", UnitRate = "Rate per unit: 110.00 up to 999999999 units" },
                new ShopDet { UtilityType = "MEPE - Generator (34162530310)", StartReading = "0", EndReading = "Nil", UnitConsumed = "", UnitRate = "Rate per unit: 200.00 up to 999999999 units" },
                new ShopDet { UtilityType = "MEPE - Sub Meter (34162530310)", StartReading = "0", EndReading = "Nil", UnitConsumed = "", UnitRate = "Rate per unit: 200.00 up to 999999999 units" },
            }
        },
    }

};
```

Kindly give me an idea for this approach?

Comment: "But it crashes" -- Can you elaborate on it. Your question is not so clear. Where does `_allGroups` come from, what is the `newGroup`'s use. Please edit to minimum issue reproducible code (consider removing unwanted comments).

Comment: crash when a search using the given search code. above I edit the code for _allgroups.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar kindly give an idea for this issue

Comment: `(PEMS.Models.ShopDet)(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue)`. Since `(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue)` results in a boolean (true/false) you're basically trying to cast a boolean to a `ShopDet`, which will crash for certain. However as far as I know this should not even compile (it knows the result of the equality check will result in a boolean that can never be cast to the `ShopDet` type, so my assumption is that you did not provide us with compiling code!

Comment: But you could try changing it to `p.MallDetails.Any(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue)`. Hard to say though, the provided code is incomplete.

Comment: Why are you casting a bool to someother class? Error log could be useful

Comment: Exactly what @Knoop pointed out (casting bool to `PEMS.Models.ShopDet`) not what you should or want to do. What you are trying to achieve is unclear.

Comment: I am posting last using code when I tried. this code not compiled and show the error cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func<ShopDet, bool>'.

Comment: You must create separate List UtilityListModel in your viewmodel and add/clear items in your ObservableCollection NOT TO create new ObservableCollection on search. The viewmodel will take care of updating ListView. Reassigning items source is pointless.

Comment: my crash code like this. var matches = group.Where(vm => vm.MallUnitNo.Contains(e.NewTextValue));   if (matches.Any())
                {

                    _expandedGroups.Add(group);
                }

Comment: @knoop p.MallDetails.Any(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue) it also shows same error cannot convert bool to 'System.Func<ShopDet, bool>

Comment: @adlorem I need this above type of UtilityListModel. how to create?

Comment: Post your model

Comment: Posted.can u check.

Comment: @Adlorem, Model really added a clarity to this question. But still the what @eve is trying to do is not clear. @eve do you want a List of `UtilityListModel` as result or a List of `ShopDet` as result? I guess you are trying to compare the inner ShopDet's `MallUnitNo` to the NewTextValue. Enlighten me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to find objects of type `ShopDet` where `MallUnitNo` is equal to `e.NewTextValue`.

```
var matches = new ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel>(group.Where(p => p.MallDetails.Contains((PEMS.Models.ShopDet)(p.MallUnitNo == e.NewTextValue))).ToList());
```

In above line

1. `group.where(` returns `ObservableCollection<ShopDets>` not `ObservableCollection<UtilityListModel>`
2. `Contains()` requires a object to be passes not a condition

Suggestions

1. Use a separate method for the selection logic like below. This really helps in debugging and improve code readability. `ShopDets` contains `MallDetails` which is a collection of `ShopDets`. May be looping is what you required inside the selection logic.

```
var matches = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet>(group.Where(p => CheckUnitNo(p)));

/* Must return true if the item as to be selected, false if not to be selected. */
private bool CheckUnitNo(ShopDet shopDet, string enteredUnitValue)
{
    //
    foreach(ShopDet shop in shopDet.MallDetails)
    {
        if (shop.MallUnitNo == enteredUnitValue)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or if you need a list of all `ShopDet` having the entered text as UnitNo than a loop before `Where` is what you might require.

Please comment for any query.... Hope this guides you in right direction..

Comment: Happy that it helped you.

Comment: Also as @Adlorem had mentioned use ObservableCollection and avoiding setting the itemsSource again. It surely is a good practice. Just an opinion

Answer (score 1):

You must create separate list in your viewmodel and add/clear items in your ObservableCollection NOT TO create new ObservableCollection on search. The viewmodel will take care of updating ListView. Reassigning items source is pointless. Example viewmodel based on your comment.

```
    public class UtilityListModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ShopDet> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShopDet>();
        public List<ShopDet> YourItemList { get; set; }
        public string LeaseName { get; set; }
        public string LeaseDate { get; set; }
        public string LeaseNo { get; set; }
        private bool _expanded;

        public UtilityListModel()
        {
            PopulateItems();
        }

        private void PopulateItems()
        {
            //STEP 1. pupulate your YourItemList with another method probably
            //STEP 2. add items to your ObservableCollection
        }

        public void SearchItems(string searchText)
        {
            //Call this method to select items from YourItemsList
            var searchResult = YourItemList.Where(....).ToList();
            //Clear items in your ObservableCollection Items
            Items.Clear();
            //Add selected items to your ObservableCollection the viewmodel will handle listview update
            foreach (var item in searchResult) // example you can also cast it.
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public string TitleWithItemCount
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", LeaseName, LeaseDate, LeaseNo); }
        }


        public bool Expanded
        {
            get { return _expanded; }
            set
            {
                if (_expanded != value)
                {
                    _expanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Expanded");
                    OnPropertyChanged("StateIcon");
                }
            }
        }

        public string StateIcon
        {
            get { return Expanded ? "twoArrowup.png" : "twoArrowdown.png"; }
        }


        public UtilityListModel(string leasename, string leaseno, string leasedate, bool expanded = true)
        {
            LeaseName = leasename;
            LeaseNo = leaseno;
            LeaseDate = leasedate;
            Expanded = expanded;
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
    public class ShopDet
    {


        public string ShopName { get; set; }
        public string ShopDate { get; set; }

        public string MallName { get; set; }
        public string MallPlace { get; set; }
        public string MallProduct { get; set; }
        public string MallUnitNo { get; set; }
        public string TimePeriod { get; set; }


        public string UtilityType { get; set; }
        public string StartReading { get; set; }
        public string EndReading { get; set; }
        public string UnitConsumed { get; set; }
        public string UnitRate { get; set; }

        public List<ShopDet> MallDetails { get; set; }
        public List<ShopDet> MeterDetails { get; set; }
        public List<ShopDet> ShopDetails { get; set; }


    }
}
```